# Occasionally reference authors' names or work titles when using numerical reference style

Tags: bibtex, citing

In my field, it is very common to use numerical type references:

> All finite subgroups of SO(3) have been classified [2].

The bibliography style I favour is acm, because it is numerical and because it makes the authors' surnames very prominent in the references. However, occasionally I want to refer to authors' names and titles of works in a sentence. For example:

> In *A course in metric geometry* [3,§2.1], Burago, Burago and Ivanov show that...

Currently I achieve this by just looking up the author names and title in my .bib file. But it would be nice if I could achieve the above by typing something like:

> In \citetitle[§2.1]{BBI}, \citeauthor*{BBI} show that...

Does anyone know of a way to do that, without vastly changing the basic bibliography format? I currently use PDFLaTeX with BibTeX, using a .bib file for all my references, and I use the amsart document class.

Comment: `Biblatex` has the `\citeauthor` and `citetitle` commands. You also can cite the year, date and url. Furthermore, its default style is numerical.